# Kotlin fake properties and their usage

Tags: kotlin

I had an idea recently of simplifying some of the code I already have in my Android app that uses Kotlin. I somewhat new to Kotlin, so any opinion would be very appreciated.

Before giving you what idea I had, I will give a base example of what code I have right now:

Lets say that in my app I have a functionality for user to log in and save his credentials for automatic future logging in. Here it is in code.

```
object MyRepository {
 // Plenty of irrelevant code here...
 fun getUserInfo(): User? {
  // Here we fetch the local data storage and check if any credentials are saved
  return userInfoDao.getUserInformation()
 }

 fun setUserInfo(user: User) {
  // Here we save user credentials to local data storage for future uses
  userInfoDao.saveUserInformation(user)
 }
}
```

This lead me to think that something like this could be done in a simpler manner, and here is the example:

```
object MyRepository {
 var userInfo: User?
   get() = userInfoDao.getUserInformation()
   set(value) = userInfoDao.saveUserInformation(value)
 }
}
```

This of course is much simpler version of what was written above. However, what I am curious is how good of a practice this is in terms of Kotlin standards and general code readability?

Comment: "This of course is much simpler version of what was written above." - How much have you omitted really? Please note that in order to give the best review possible, we need to get as much context as possible.

Comment: @SimonForsberg what I am talking about is that in my opinion, using one variable instead of 2 functions is a much simpler approach to coding. What I omitted has no contextual benefits to the code I provided.

Comment: I will personally let it be for now, but I would like to take the opportunity to point out - in case you are not aware - that there is a close reason on this site which is: *Missing Review Context: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site.*

Comment: I would personally give this a green signal. I can't say much about it as am myself very new to the development world, but our team has a  2yo product with a significant database and we use code similar to this for accessing sharedPreferences but not really in local databases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, I would not expect a database call to be made simply by referring to a property, such as with `val user = MyRepository.userInfo`. If a database call is being made, it's better to have a function for it.

I'd even argue that it would even be better to name the function `fetchUserInformation` than `getUserInformation` to be clear that this is not just a simple getter.

Comment: To elaborate on this, I would use getters/setters on properties exclusively for computed properties, i.e. derived from some other properties in the class.